# Can't switch on wifi

Tags: networking, wifi-hardware-switch

Recently I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my HP 630 and when I try to turn on wifi, it does not work. I have read somewhere that it may be the wifi button  but it doesn't turn on and the <kbd>fn</kbd> works with the volume or scrn brightness. I use a Qualcomm Atheros ar9285 card and the driver is installed. The only problem is that I cannot connect to the wifi.
On Windows 7 it worked, so the button itself is working.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsmod | grep hp` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0280]'; rfkill list`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have had some bad experiences with some HP laptops in this regard. There may be a BIOS or similar bug that doesn't properly un-kill the radio chips. The only workaround I have found is to try to enable WiFi in BIOS or POST and avoid disabling it in hardware once booted. If you need to disable WiFi, try to do it in software.

To verify that I'm not completely wrong in my assumptions, could you please show the output of `rfkill list`? If WiFi is hard blocked as well as soft blocked, then it could be the bug I mentioned.

Comment: 0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: yes
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: yes
3: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: I am trying to enable it.

Comment: i tried also from settings to enable it. When i click on the switch automatically goes off

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't really consider this a _solution_, just a workaround. And a rather awkward one at that, if you have to *not* hit a button or key that is meant to be pressed.

Comment: If you mean software settings, I'm not surprised. the output of `rfkill list` says both WiFi and Bluetooth are hard blocked, so a software switch shouldn't be able to override that.

Comment: Hey
when i started up my laptop i was pressing several times on wifi button and after that it worked and the rfkill list does not show anymore that wifi is hard blocked. 
Now it is working perfectly.
Thank you for help